# Dynamic GreaterThanOrEqual using Expressions in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, predicate

I'm facing a little problem I'm stuck on.
I'm building queries dynamically, they will be used by LINQ to query the database. The calculation must be done on the database side (client-side evaluation is not efficient, therefore I would like no to use it)

I have two Expressions that are used to compute a special mathematical operation (For this context, it has been simplified). They are represented as :

```
public static Expression<Func<Circle, float>> REAL_HEIGHT_EXPR = circle => circle.Diameter * circle.Paper.Height;
public static Expression<Func<Circle, float>> REAL_Y_EXPR = circle => circle.Y * circle.Paper.Height - REAL_HEIGHT_EXPR.Invoke(circle) * (float)0.5;
```

I'm searching for records in the database that are in a min-max range. Since there will be multiple pairs of min-max, I'm also using LinqKit (https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) with `PredicateBuilder`. This `PredicateBuilder` will be built gradually and then used in a LINQ .Where(predicate).

Let's say, for example, that we have two pairs of min-max with the values `[0,1]` and `[4,5]`. The SQL query that should be executed would be :

```
(REAL_Y_EXPR >= 0 AND REAL_Y_EXPR <= 1) OR (REAL_Y_EXPR >= 4 AND REAL_Y_EXPR <= 5)
```

Where REAL_Y_EXPR is the result of the expression defined above, using the Circle class and parameters. (The result of the computation, which is a float, and executed in the database side)

Here's a snippet of the function building the predicate:

```
public static ExpressionStarter<Circle> GetMinMaxPredicate(List<SearchMinMax> searchList, Expression<Func<Circle, float>> expr)
        {
            var allParametersSearch = PredicateBuilder.New<Circle>();
            if (searchList != null)
            {
                searchList.ForEach(value =>
                {
                    var searchPredicateAND = PredicateBuilder.New<Circle>();
                    if (value.Min != null)
                    {
                        searchPredicateAND = searchPredicateAND.And(circle => expr.Invoke(circle) >= value.Min);
                    }

                    if (value.Max != null)
                    {
                        searchPredicateAND = searchPredicateAND.And(circle => expr.Invoke(circle) <= value.Max);
                    }

                    allParametersSearch = allParametersSearch.Or(searchPredicateAND);
                });
            }

            return allParametersSearch;
        }
```

The main reason I'm doing all of that, is to have a fully reusable code and prevent rewriting the expression multiple times.

However, this code is not working, since I'm forced to call .Invoke(), LINQ will throws that I need to call ToList() or other methods to do a client-side evaluation. (I have also tested using REAL_HEIGHT_EXPR which doesn't have an `Invoke()`, and it's the same error, so not coming from that part)

The main problem I'm having is the `<=` and `>=`. Since it changes and I would like to use the same expression without having to rewrite all of them multiple times with the operand included.

I have tried to use `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual` with the expression already written (which would be great!)

```
Expression searchAND = Expression.Empty();
searchAND = Expression.AndAlso(searchAND, Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression.Constant(value.Min), REAL_Y_EXPR);
```

However, the `searchAND` line throws the following error :

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Linq.Expressions.dll: 'The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types 'System.Single' and 'System.Func`2[My.NameSpace.Circle,System.Single]'.'
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedBinaryOperatorOrThrow(ExpressionType binaryType, String name, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetComparisonOperator(ExpressionType binaryType, String opName, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Expression left, Expression right)
```

Would anyone have an idea on how to solve that ?

Comment: Have you added AsExpandable to your query?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That was it. Thanks a lot, I didn't understand what .AsExpandable() was doing at first, but now I get it. It replaces all the invokes with the standard lambda/expression and allows db-side evaluation